# Can't connect USB 3.0 storage device to my RHEL 8.8 VM

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, redhat-enterprise-linux, esxi

System details:

- RHEL 8.8 VM
- ESXi 6.5

**Problem**: Attaching my USB to the VM as a storage device.
The USB port on my laptop is a 3.2. The USB key is a USB 3.0.

When I try attaching it to the VM, I get the errors listed below:

```
[519002.985348] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[519003.163267] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 56 using ehci-pci
[519003.180165] usb 1-1: Invalid ep0 maxpacket: 9
[519003.298280] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 57 using ehci-pci
[519003.317998] usb 1-1: Invalid ep0 maxpacket: 9
[519003.323299] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

But, if I plug in a USB 2.0 drive into the same USB slot, that one connects to the VM, no issues.

I would try adding a file in `/etc/modprobe.d` called  `disable-uas.conf` and add a line similar to this:

```
options usb-storage quirks=21c4:0cc7:u
```

But unfortunately, RHEL doesn't see the drive, therefore I cannot get the `idvendor` and `idproduct`. Similar to this:

```
[353100.609396] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[353100.979162] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=21c4, idProduct=0cc7, bcdDevice=11.00
[353100.979173] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[353100.979180] usb 1-1: Product: USB Flash Drive
[353100.979186] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Lexar
[353100.979191] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 576EBADSYLR6RLN2
[353100.984665] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[353100.985634] scsi host34: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[353102.739453] scsi 34:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Lexar    USB Flash Drive  1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[353102.739697] scsi 34:0:0:0: alua: supports implicit and explicit TPGS
[353102.739704] scsi 34:0:0:0: alua: No target port descriptors found
[353102.740438] sd 34:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[353102.758080] sd 34:0:0:0: [sdd] 60620800 512-byte logical blocks: (31.0 GB/28.9 GiB)
[353102.768101] sd 34:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[353102.768109] sd 34:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[353102.776265] sd 34:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[353102.837641]  sdd: sdd1
[353102.882526] sd 34:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[353106.593692] fat__get_entry: 214 callbacks suppressed
```

Comment: Did you connect the USB drive to your guest machine and disconnect it from host machine in the the VM app menu.

Comment: Hi John

I opend a remote console to the VM and at the top right of the console is the icon to attach the USB drive. When i mouse over it, is tells me my USB drive info, so the console sees it, but when i attach it, RHEL8 complains. So this is definitely a RHEL8 issue.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue.
log into vmware, navigate to your VM and right click on the VM to access settings. checked to see if I had the controller for USB 3.0, I did not. I added it. Now my VM recognizes USB keys using USB 3.0.

As for mass storage devices, I have a SanDisk extreme 1TB SSD drive that connects via USB 3.0
When i try mounting it to the VM, even though is recognizes the drive, it umounts it automatically.
I added the idproduct and idvendor values to a file called disable-uas.conf in /etc/modprobe.d and that also fixed my issue.